# How do I launch a program on a specific side of a workspace on startup?

Tags: i3

I've got this at the bottom of `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace $ws1; exec i3-sensible-terminal ranger; exec i3-sensible-terminal btop'
```

But when I start i3wm, it's a coinflip whether `ranger` will open on the left or right of `btop`. I want `btop` to be on the left side of workspace 1 and `ranger` to be on the right.